# How to split the value of one columns with into two columns with multiple word

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to use the below values into different columns inside the table now they are storing into one i tried REGEXP_SUBSTR but still i can't use them separately .. any help would be apricated

`

```
SELECT
REGEXP_SUBSTR('One Thousand Four Hundred Forty Six', '[^ ]+', 1, level) AS parts
FROM dual
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('One Thousand Four Hundred Forty Six', '[^ ]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL;


the output should be like this : 

column A : One Thousand
column B : Four Hundred
column C : Forty Six
```

`

the above is my attempt

Comment: Be more precise about the rule you want to apply. An example is just an example, and we can only guess what you really want. Is it always pairs of two words? Or is it about numbers? Do you want "two hundred thousand three hundred twenty" to be split into pairs of two words? "two hundred" - "thousand three" - "hundred twenty" (while the meaning would rather be "two hundred thousand" + three hundred" + "twenty" of course)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your pattern to:

```
'[^ ]+( [^ ]+)?'
```

then it will find one word optionally followed by a space and another word - so it would still work if you started with an odd number of words.

Then your query could be:

```
SELECT
REGEXP_SUBSTR('One Thousand Four Hundred Forty Six', '[^ ]+( [^ ]+)?', 1, level) AS parts
FROM dual
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('One Thousand Four Hundred Forty Six', '[^ ]+( [^ ]+)?', 1, level) IS NOT NULL;
```

| PARTS |
| --- |
| One Thousand |
| Four Hundred |
| Forty Six |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TycJszZC)

If you want them split into separate *columns* rather than rows then you would need to know how many to allow for - i.e. the maximum number of words you might have to handle. Then instead of a hierarchical query you can do:

```
SELECT
REGEXP_SUBSTR('One Thousand Four Hundred Forty Six', '[^ ]+( [^ ]+)?', 1, 1) AS part1,
REGEXP_SUBSTR('One Thousand Four Hundred Forty Six', '[^ ]+( [^ ]+)?', 1, 2) AS part2,
REGEXP_SUBSTR('One Thousand Four Hundred Forty Six', '[^ ]+( [^ ]+)?', 1, 3) AS part3
FROM dual
```

| PART1 | PART2 | PART3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One Thousand | Four Hundred | Forty Six |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ow1auXhS)

Comment: Hi thanks for your time and effort , i got the query right but now i want to store each column into a variable for example  "One Thousand"  into FRST_NAME , i tried to separate them through With and ROWNUM <2 but it won't work .

Comment: What kind of variable - are you doing this in PL/SQL, or do you mean substitution variables, or just in a CTE - in which case just wrapping the second query in a `with` should work - [like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/4lReiMXD)? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve - and it might be better to ask a new question explaining what you're really doing and where you are now stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You have the regex `[^ ]+` that find a word (adjacent characters with no blank).

You want a regex that finds two words (a word, a blank, a word): `[^ ]+ [^ ]+`.

```
SELECT
REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '[^ ]+ [^ ]+', 1, level) AS parts
FROM (select 'One Thousand Four Hundred Forty Six' as str from dual)
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '[^ ]+ [^ ]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for the answer please see the above comment

Comment: With the "above" comment you are probably refering to the comment you made under Alex Poole's answer? I have the same problem as Alex, I don't know what exactly you mean. When talking about variables, you are probably talking about PL/SQL? In that case fetch the first row and put its string into the first_name variable, fetch the second row, put it in a nother variable and so on.

Comment: By the way: It seems you haven't read the comment I wrote under your request.